# Joomla Virtuemart tax rules - US States not available

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

The Virtuemart Tax & Calculations doesn't show the US States in the select box. So I cant setup tax per state. I read this is a JavaScript conflict. How would I resolve this so the states display? I included a screencapture image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtuemart version 3.0.14 has a bug that causes the US States to be unavailable in the tax rules. 
Updating to Virtuemart version 3.0.16 resolves the bug.